# Simple Excel Macro - Not Getting Expected Results, Hitting a Brick Wall

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having some trouble with something I'm working on and was hoping someone might be able to help me (fairly novice) with finding what I'm doing wrong in this Excel Macro.

I have two worksheets, one containing data, one containing conditions (Worker Names, Date and Month names) needed for calculating stats of the data sheet.  The Macro is being written to give a breakdown of the number of a certain task that a given range of workers have performed for a given range of Months and Years.  The twist is that I'm trying to identify dates that are unique among the list of dates that any given worker performed a task.

For example, if the worker completed the task twice on 01/05/2017 and once each on 01/06/2017, 01/07/2017, and 01/08/2017 - I am trying to get a return answer of four for that worker because only four days were used despite there being five tasks completed.

I was having a lot of problems with date formatting for the .Value array vs the Date array but I think I have that corrected.  The problem I'm running into is that my output data doesn't match what it should and the figures sometimes are up in the high 60's to hundreds which isn't possible for a single month.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I know that this task is accomplishable using formulas, but I have an insane amount of data and it is eating up to much processing power. Here is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim Data() As Variant
Dim Dates() As Variant

Data = Worksheets("Master List").Range("A2:" & "P" & Worksheets("Master    List").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Value

ReDim Dates(0 To 0)
DataLengthX = UBound(Data, 1)
MonthCount = 0

For i = 41 To 76

    MonthYear = Worksheets("Daily Count").Cells(i, 1).Value

    For p = 3 To 27

        DateNum = 0
        ReDim Dates(0 To 0)
        ReviewerName = Worksheets("Daily Count").Cells(40, p).Value

        For x = 1 To DataLengthX

            DateMatch = False

            If ReviewerName = Data(x, 8) And MonthYear = Data(x, 12) Then

                For Z = 0 To UBound(Dates, 1)

                    If Format(Dates(Z), "m/d/yyyy") = Format(Data(x, 9), "m/d/yyyy") Then

                        DateMatch = True
                        Exit For

                    End If

                Next Z

                If DateMatch = False Then

                    ReDim Dates(0 To DateNum)
                    Dates(DateNum) = Format(Data(x, 9), "m/d/yyyy")
                    DateNum = DateNum + 1

                End If

            End If

        Next x

        If UBound(Dates, 1) <> 0 Then

            Worksheets("Daily Count").Cells(i, p) = UBound(Dates, 1) + 1

        Else

            Worksheets("Daily Count").Cells(i, p) = 0

        End If

    Next p

Next i
```

Comment: Difficult to know what each of these loops are doing as you've not commented any of the code, but do you intend to only ever redim dates and not redim preserve on this line? "ReDim Dates(0 To DateNum)"

Comment: @Zerk comments should say *why*, not *what* - it's difficult to know what each of these loops are doing because the variables are poorly named.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother with a macro - I'd use a helper column to identify duplicate dates for a worker, and then a `=COUNTIF()` to get the number of unique days per worker.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the i loop is referencing a column of Months/Years i.e. "January 2016," the p loop is referencing a row of employee names, and the x loop is examining a date of task column in the data (Data(X,9).  For each month and each employee is examined, then the Date field is examined to identify unique values.  Sorry I'm not familiar with Preserve, I am wiping the array each time X starts for the i and p loops because I'm dealing with a different month/year and employee.  I've already tried formulas and got the results needed but data volume is too high for these.

Comment: @Zerk - Thank you so much!  That solved the problem, I wasn't familiar with preserve and didn't realize the data was wiping every time I resized the array!